# Asking about galvanometer spiral spring torsion due to torque

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-current, torque

in this question, someone told me the answer is (A) not (B) although after giving it a good amount of brain cells I am still not convinced, shouldn't it be (B) since the torque happening due to magnetic flux hitting the current in the wire equal to the spring torsion, because of the law of conversation of energy, what am I missing here. and yes I know it says before equilibrium.

[image]

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation, energy is not conserved.  When the current is first applied, the torque it supplies will be greater than that from the spring. This will cause an angular acceleration, with an increase in angular velocity and kinetic energy. The needle will swing past the new equilibrium (where the torques are equal), and then oscillate briefly as the energy is dissipated to friction.

Comment: thank you so much man!